# a new dataframe based on summary statistics of an existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data from an existing dataframe:

```
      Unnamed: 0         clOrdId                transactTime   symbol side  lastPx  lastQty
0              0  order__1000157     2021-05-28 09:45:54.923  1000157    S  0.9883     10.0
1              1  order__1000157     2021-05-28 09:45:23.500  1000157    S  0.9883     43.0
2              2  order__1000157     2021-05-28 09:26:38.129  1000157    S  0.9863     53.0
3              3  order__1000055     2021-05-28 09:24:16.837  1000055    S  0.9798     53.0
4              4  order__1000089     2021-05-28 09:24:11.027  1000089    B  0.9782     52.9
...          ...             ...                         ...      ...  ...     ...      ...
7296        5464  order-1AR1SCvx  2020-11-30 12:00:17.225000  1000065    B  0.9750    100.0
7297        5465  order-1AR1DUwx  2020-11-30 12:00:17.223000  1000065    B  0.9825    100.0
7298        5466  order-1AR1lQNx  2020-11-28 21:13:48.334000  1000114    S  0.9795     10.0
7299        5467  order-1AR1RvSx  2020-11-28 12:19:10.714000  1000065    S  1.0050    100.0
7300        5468  order-1AR1gSLx  2020-11-28 07:58:09.907000  1000065    B  0.9860    100.0
```

I want to create a **new summary statistics dataframe** based on the `symbol` and `lastPx` columns such that for each symbol i can see the mean, std, min & max of the last price.

So the expected result (example data) might look like this:

```
        symbol      min     max     mean    std
0       1000055     0.092   1.01    1.00    0.03
1       1000089     0.091   1.02    0.99    0.04
2       1000065     0.091   1.05    1.02    0.02
3       1000114     0.091   1.01    0.98    0.01
...     ...         ...     ...     ...     ...
5000    1000157     0.091   1.01    1.00    0.02
5001    1000158     0.091   1.02    1.00    0.03
5002    1000159     0.091   1.03    1.01    0.04
```

I have come across `df.describe()`, but that does not seem to work in the way that is required where i need to see each `symbol` listed uniquely. My alternative is to recreate a new dataframe piece by piece, but this does not seem to be an optimal method.

Is there a quick (pythonic) way of implementing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

try via `groupby()`,`agg()` and `reset_index()`:

```
out=df.groupby('symbol')['lastPx'].agg(['min','max','mean','std']).reset_index()
```

Comment: I have marked this as the correct answer because it appears to be the fastest and easiest of the solutions proposed.

Comment: Follow up question:   if i wanted to group using two columns 9say `symbol` and `side` in this example,  how would this be implemented please ?

Comment: @D.L in that case just pass the `list` of columns in `groupby()` method: `df.groupby(['symbol','side'])['lastPx'].agg(['min','max','mean','std']).reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

```
df.pivot_table(index='symbol', aggfunc=['min','max','mean','std'], values ='lastPx')
```

Comment: This is a good answer and produces a working solution (yet to test on speed), so i have upvoted. However, the other answer (using `groupby()` seems to produce a flat df, so it might be slightly easier to work with...  Was wondering if you had considered that or your thoughts ?

Comment: The `groupby()` method appears to be 2 to 3 times faster than the `pivot_table` method (for 7000 rows of data). Both produce the same results